# C++ const reference parameter optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, reference, constants

I'm having a little trouble understanding how this would be compiled and I don't understand the assembly output enough to judge.

```
struct RectI {
    int left; int top; int right; int bottom;

    ...

    BOOL Intersects(const RectI& rc)
    {
        return (!(left > rc.right || right < rc.left || top > rc.bottom || bottom < rc.top));
    }
    BOOL Intersects(int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        return Intersects(RectI(l, t, r, b));
    }
};
```

For the method `Intersects(int, int, int, int)`, it immediately calls `Intersects(const RectI&)`. Will this require that an entirely new structure
is created in memory, constructed and then passed to `Intersects(const RectI&)` or will this be optimized down since the parameter is a const reference?

Comment: It must behave as if it created a temporary. Whether the temporary creation can be optimized away depends on other factors such as whether `RectI`'s constructor and destructor have side effects.

Comment: The constructor is very simple, it just assigns the four values to the member data and is inlined also.

Comment: const& doesn't stop the object creation during the function call.

Comment: You could fix this by implementing the first one in terms of the second one, then no temporary object is required at all.

Comment: Then it *can* be optimized way in theory. Whether the optimizer does so in practice is a quality of implementation issue. I wouldn't worry about this unless you have profiling data showing that `Intersects` is actually a bottleneck.

Comment: @KaidulIslam theoretically not, but as T.C. says, in the generated assembly code there is no requirement for an object to be created

Comment: So it would be a better idea to reverse the calls? or to simply create duplicate code for both methods?

Comment: I would make the second one have the logic and the first one call the second one

Comment: If you're using C++ and it's 2014, why are you using a macro/typedef for `bool`?

Comment: Making a legacy app for my own use... not really concerned with formalities of the language. I just use the Win32 defines for consistency, although RECT doesn't provide the interface I need.

Comment: @GeneralTso It seems like your making a simple 2D application, may I suggest SDL2? The Win32 API hurts most developers eyes.

Comment: I haven't programmed much since DOS/Win16. My app really doesn't have an interface. It's just cropping ESRI polygons into cells. I'd prefer to stick as closely to C as possible because C++ scares me. Templates make my head hurt. I am liking the member functions of structs, though.

Comment: @GeneralTso `struct` is actually just a `class` that defaults to `public` rather than `private` in c++, that's why you can declare member functions. SDL2 is a fully C api, and I can tell from your public member variables (no encapsulation) and usage of `struct` that you want to stick close to C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *should* be inlined and optimised, assuming the constructor (which you forgot to show us) is simple and defined inline. But the only way to be sure is to look at the assembly output.

I put together this test case:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef bool BOOL;

struct RectI {
    int left; int top; int right; int bottom;

    RectI(int l, int t, int r, int b) : left(l), top(t), right(r), bottom(b) {}

    BOOL Intersects(const RectI& rc) { return (!(left > rc.left || right < rc.right || top > rc.bottom || bottom < rc.top)); }
    BOOL Intersects(int l, int t, int r, int b) { return Intersects(RectI(l, t, r, b)); }
};

int main()
{
    // Read from input, to prevent the entire calculation being optimised out
    int l,t,r,b;
    std::cin >> l >> t >> r >> b;

    RectI rt(l,t,r,b);    
    return rt.Intersects(1,2,3,4);   
}
```

Compiled and dissassembled thusly:

```
g++ -O3 test.cpp
objdump -dC a.out
```

with output containing

```
00000000004005d0 <main>:
  4005d0:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  4005d4:       bf 40 10 60 00          mov    $0x601040,%edi
  4005d9:       48 89 e6                mov    %rsp,%rsi
  4005dc:       e8 df ff ff ff          callq  4005c0 <std::istream::operator>>(int&)@plt>
  4005e1:       48 8d 74 24 04          lea    0x4(%rsp),%rsi
  4005e6:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4005e9:       e8 d2 ff ff ff          callq  4005c0 <std::istream::operator>>(int&)@plt>
  4005ee:       48 8d 74 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rsi
  4005f3:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4005f6:       e8 c5 ff ff ff          callq  4005c0 <std::istream::operator>>(int&)@plt>
  4005fb:       48 8d 74 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rsi
  400600:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400603:       e8 b8 ff ff ff          callq  4005c0 <std::istream::operator>>(int&)@plt>
  400608:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40060a:       83 3c 24 01             cmpl   $0x1,(%rsp)
  40060e:       8b 74 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%esi
  400612:       8b 54 24 08             mov    0x8(%rsp),%edx
  400616:       8b 4c 24 04             mov    0x4(%rsp),%ecx
  40061a:       7e 05                   jle    400621 <main+0x51>
  40061c:       48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  400620:       c3                      retq   
  400621:       83 fa 02                cmp    $0x2,%edx
  400624:       7e f6                   jle    40061c <main+0x4c>
  400626:       83 f9 04                cmp    $0x4,%ecx
  400629:       7f f1                   jg     40061c <main+0x4c>
  40062b:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40062d:       83 ee 01                sub    $0x1,%esi
  400630:       0f 9f c0                setg   %al
  400633:       eb e7                   jmp    40061c <main+0x4c>
  400635:       66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40063c:       00 00 00 00
```

You can see there are four function calls (the `callq` instructions) to read from the input; the remainder consists of inline comparisons, with no further function calls: both calls to `Intersects`, and both constructor calls, have been inlined.

Your compiler may vary.

Answer (score -2):

The second function creates an object of type RectI using the RectI constructor and passes a constant reference to the first function. The object is actually created.

Hope that helps.

Carles.